# How can I transfer to a sheet if range says "Fail" in any cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a data entry form and I'm looking for if any of the results say "fail" to send the user to a different sheet for additional testing, but if they all pass to proceed as normal.

I have tried If Range ("R5:R20") = Fail Then

But it bugs out.

```
 Sub RecordBathTest()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "G:\QA\Compliance\Bath Testing\Results\Form 8241B - Bath Test 
Log.xlsx"
Windows("Data Entry Log.xlsm").Activate
Range("D5:S20").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Form 8241B - Bath Test Log.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("2019").Select
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Windows("Data Entry Log.xlsm").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
If Range("R5:R20").Value = "Fail" Then

Sheets("Bath Test Failure Log").Select

 Else
  Range("D5:E20,G5:P20,R5:S20").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Windows("Form 8241B - Bath Test Log.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
Windows("Data Entry Log.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Test Start").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End If

End Sub
```

I get

> Run-Time error '13':
>   Type Mismatch

And it says it doesn't like my Range selection If statement

Comment: Instead of `If Range("R5:R20").Value = "Fail"` count if any cell in that range is equal to fail with `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("R5:R20"),"Fail")>0 Then... Else...End If`

Answer (score 2):

You can't evaluate cells in a range simultaneously - you need to go through each cell in the range and evaluate one by one. This can be done with a `for` loop (think ***for each of the cells from R5 to R20, find if the value is 'Fail'***). Replace the following lines:

```
If Range("R5:R20").Value = "Fail" Then

Sheets("Bath Test Failure Log").Select

 Else
  Range("D5:E20,G5:P20,R5:S20").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Windows("Form 8241B - Bath Test Log.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
Windows("Data Entry Log.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Test Start").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End If
```

with

```
check = 0
For Each cell In Range("R5:R20")
    If cell.Value = "Fail" Then
        check = 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell

If check = 1 Then
    Sheets("Bath Test Failure Log").Select
Else
    Range("D5:E20,G5:P20,R5:S20").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Windows("Form 8241B - Bath Test Log.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Windows("Data Entry Log.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Test Start").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End If
```

This should solve your immediate problem, but I would advise restructuring your code to reference objects rather than using activate, and trying to avoid `Select` where possible